# Add data as channel to keras model

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have the following model:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(units=X_train.shape[1],activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(units=X_train.shape[1]/4,activation='tanh', activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(1e-2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))#, bias_initializer=output_bias))
optimzier = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss=BinaryFocalLoss(gamma=2), optimizer=optimzier, metrics = [f1_m,Precision(name='precision')])
```

Now I want to change the model, so it will handle data with two channels.

In case it matters, my data is:

`X_train` is a dataframe with 200 columns (features) - columns 1-10 are categorical, columns 11-100 are channel #1 and columns 101-190 are channel #2 (so that column 11 and 101 are the same feature and another channel, and so on).

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this question with respect to the input of the model? Unclear, please re-frame.

Comment: @ParthShah No , I want to change the model

Comment: There is no LSTM in this model, and it's unclear what the difference between columns 11-100 and 101-190 are. And where is channel #2?

Comment: Currently the input is one vector with 180 dimensions. I want to change it so it will get 2d matrix of 90X2 - 90 features with 2 channels.

Comment: "Features" and "channels" are same from a Keras network's standpoint, both go on last dim. The format is `(samples, *spatial_dims, channels)` - so you ask to have _two_ channels dims, which can't be done. You have two options: (1) treat "features" as spatial dims and put "channels" in last dim, so `(batch_size, 90, 2)` - but `Dense` will treat the 90 as timesteps, which likely isn't desired; (2) make a dual input network, one input handling features 1-90, other 91-180

Comment: @overlordgolddragon can u elaborate on dual input network? Do u have an example and what is the meaning of applying this on the network?

Comment: I don't know what problem you're trying to solve; what is the task? What sort of data - what are the "channels" and "features" (images, stocks, ...)? In general `Dense` can do "OK" on any input format, but it needs to be shaped properly. If you have a mix of categorical and non-categorical features you need to transform them to a common (one or the other) - else decision trees (e.g. XGBoost) are more suitable.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon This is data of the same features from 2 source. So think for examples that I have 2 sensors for temperature, 2 sensors for humidity, etc.
I want the for the same feature (temperature), the 2 sensors will be considered as 2 "channels"

Comment: Then they're all features, and you can concatenate them all along the features dimension (i.e. last dim), with shape `(samples, 180)`; the network will learn to relate these appropriately. I also see it's a binary classification problem from the loss function, but info about the input data remains incomplete (e.g. what are the other 20 columns); it'd be best to give a more complete dataset description.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The other columns are just categorical one-hot-encoded features

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to state as follows, please let me know if I am getting something wrong,

1. The columns 1-10 of `x_train` contains categorical data. For the sake of my solution, I am thinking of the categories defined as integer labels.
2. The columns 11-100 contains non-categorical data. For the sake of my solution, I am thinking of them as some random float values.
3. The columns 101-190 are also same as stated in point 2.
4. You are considering column batch (11-100) and (101-190) as two channels. I am assuming you are expecting the same type of processing (sub-models) for both of the channels.

If my assumptions are correct, you should split the columns stated in points 1, 2, and 3. Then you should feed them to the model. Let me show you what I designed for this case with the Keras model image.

[image: keras model]

The model processes each of the same data types (categorical/non-categorical) and processes them differently based on the learned weights. Then the information is merged and it generates a final output. I am adding the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# number of categories
nb_category = 10
# number of rows in data
rows = 100

# Column 1 to 10 = 10-1+1 = 10 features
# The input is a plain array of integer categories wihtout one hot encoding
categories = np.random.randint(nb_category, size=(rows, 10))
# Column 11 to 100 = 100-11+1 = 90 features
channel1 = np.random.rand(rows, 90)
# Column 101 to 190 = 190-101+1 = 90 features
channel2 = np.random.rand(rows, 90)
# generating a random output for each of the rows
y_train = np.random.rand(rows)

def modelDef(cat_shape, ch1_shape, ch2_shape):
    cat_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=cat_shape)
    ch1_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=ch1_shape)
    ch2_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=ch2_shape)

    # shallow model for category inputs
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(cat_in)
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(cat_x)
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(cat_x)

    # shallow model for channel inputs
    ch1_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(ch1_in)
    ch1_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(ch1_x)
    ch1_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(ch1_x)

    # shallow model for channel inputs
    ch2_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(ch2_in)
    ch2_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)(ch2_x)
    ch2_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(ch2_x)

    # merging all the outputs
    out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([cat_x, ch1_x, ch2_x])
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(out)
    
    # generating model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[cat_in, ch1_in, ch2_in], 
                           outputs=out, name="dummyModel")
    
    # Tune the loss, optimizer, metrics according to the data
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',
                  metrics='accuracy')
    return model

model = modelDef(categories.shape[1:], channel1.shape[1:], channel2.shape[1:])

model.fit([categories, channel1, channel2], y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=10)
```

For the sake of my simplicity, I have generated random data. The `categories` define the data columns as stated in point 1. The `channel1` and `channel2` defies the data columns as stated in points 2 and 3, respectively. I tried to keep the code as simple as possible, therefore, I avoided declaring optional parameters.

Furthermore, as you are saying that the columns stated in point 2 and 3 contain the same feature, you may want them to go through the same training weights. To simplify my statement, I am adding a modified version of the previous architecture.

[image]

The model utilizes the channel 2 and 3 with the same learned weights. Also, training params are reduced. The modified function of the model is given below.

```
def modelDefMod(cat_shape, ch1_shape, ch2_shape):
    cat_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=cat_shape)
    ch1_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=ch1_shape)
    ch2_in = tf.keras.Input(shape=ch2_shape)

    # shallow model for category inputs
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(cat_in)
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)(cat_x)
    cat_x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16)(cat_x)

    # defining weights
    d1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
    d2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64)
    d3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)

    # shallow model for channel inputs
    ch1_x = d1(ch1_in)
    ch1_x = d2(ch1_x)
    ch1_x = d3(ch1_x)

    # shallow model for channel inputs
    ch2_x = d1(ch2_in)
    ch2_x = d2(ch2_x)
    ch2_x = d3(ch2_x)

    # merging all the outputs
    out = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([cat_x, ch1_x, ch2_x])
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(12)(out)
    out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(out)
    
    # generating model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[cat_in, ch1_in, ch2_in], 
                           outputs=out, name="dummyModel")
    
    # Tune the loss, optimizer, metrics according to the data
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam',
                  metrics='accuracy')
    return model
```